# jQuery, resetting form value in a toggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I'm using the JQuery toggle() function to allow a user to add a new value to a select box dynamically within a form.

If the user clicks "Add", a DIV is shown with an input box in it and the "Add" text is changed to "Remove".

In the case where a user clicks "Add", then enters some text in the new input box, then clicks "Remove", I want to clear the input box.

Everything here works, but I am unclear how to reset the form value of the newly created input box in the case where the user toggles "remove"

Here's my code

```
$(".newName").click(function(){
    var frm = $(this).closest("form"); 

    $(".newContainer", frm).toggle(); // toggles the newContainer to show or hide
    $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Add' ? 'Remove' : 'Add'); // changes our text 
    $("#nameList", frm).prop('disabled', $(this).text() != 'Add') // disables the original list if we are adding a new one

});

<div class="names">
    <form id="newForm">
        <select id="nameList"></select>
        <p><a href="#" class="newName">Add</a></p>
        <div class="newContainer">
            <input type="text" id="theNewName" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Unless you have a `<frm>` element in your page, the second line is incorrect.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question a bit so that I can understand what are you trying to do and what's not working?

Comment: Sorry guys, looks like my original post missed the HTML I added that and it should be more clear.

Comment: Bishnu, that was a mis type on my part. Please see the updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".newName").click(function(){
    var frm = $(this).closest("form"); 

    $(".newContainer", frm).toggle(); // toggles the newContainer to show or hide
    if($(this).text() == 'Remove'){$("#nameList", frm).val('');}
    $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Add' ? 'Remove' : 'Add'); // changes our text 

    $("#nameList", frm).prop('disabled', $(this).text() != 'Add') // disables the original list if we are adding a new one

});
```

If you are worried about text ("Add"/"Remove") getting changed + some optimization:

```
<a href="#" class="newName add" data-add-text="Add" data-remove-text="Remove">
Add
</a>


$('body').on('click',".newName",function(){
    var frm = $(this).closest("form"); 
    $(".newContainer", frm).toggle();
    $("#nameList", frm).val('').prop('disabled', $(this).hasClass('remove'));
    var newText = $(this).hasClass('remove')?
        $(this).data('addText'):$(this).data('removeText');
    $(this).text(newText).toggleClass('add remove');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sabith, any slicker way of doing that besides checking the value of the text?

Comment: @JasonWells Are you worried about the text getting changed in future or on reducing code?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".newName").click(function(){
    var frm = $(this).closest("form");

    $(".newContainer", frm).toggle(); // toggles the newContainer to show or hide
    $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Add' ? 'Remove' : 'Add'); // changes our text
    if($(this).text() == 'Remove' )
    {
    $("#theNewName",frm).val('');
    }
    $("#nameList", frm).prop('disabled', $(this).text() != 'Add') // disables the original list if we are adding a new one

});
```

See demo here : [http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/abdYJ/)